# Unity dashboard does not start on desktop

Tags: unity, unity-dash

If I've focused any application or my mouse is over launcher or top panel, dashboard works just fine. But when my mouse is on the desktop background, dashboard does not show on super-key-tap. What I've tried:

**unity --replace** - no result

**disable wallch** - no result

**changing wallpapers manually** - no result

**logging off** - no result

**rebooting whole system** - no result

This is second time I've experienced such a problem, last time I had to reinstall my whole system, but it was when I was tweaking the Nvidia drivers.

Running on Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit with nVidia GeForce 635M on Unity DE.

Answer (score 0):

Try `unity --reset` and be aware that this will reset all your Unity settings to default.

Comment: Now it says "ERROR: reset option is now deprecated"