# no launcher, no dash, no unity, how to get back to my desktop?

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher

FYI, I have tried these, but none worked as of yet! Please help! I must not want to reinstall Ubuntu precise:

- [AskUbuntu:Unity Launcher missing](https://askubuntu.com/q/263206/176470)
- [AskUbuntu: Unity doesn't load](https://askubuntu.com/q/17381/176470)
- [Youtube:Restore missing    launcher](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMTkx8y1K88)
- [AskUbuntu:Unity 3D no longer works!](https://askubuntu.com/q/125608/176470)

Is there any other way to find a solution, any help is highly appreciated!
Please do ask for any further info u may need to point me to a better direction.

1. **Edit**: I have still the opportunity to use `ctrl+Alt+T` for the terminal. And from there I used `firefox &` to get the browser on.
2. **Edit 2**: Tried to find more; found more explained situation

   - https://askubuntu.com/q/260578/176470.
3. **Edit 3**:@Adithya: tried that no luck! Here is what my terminal gave me so far...

   ```
   [1447:22] (~) bash $ unity --reset
   WARNING: Unity currently default profile, so switching to metacity while resetting the values
   unity-panel-service: no process found
   Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
   Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
   Backend     : gconf
   Integration : true
   Profile     : unity
   Adding plugins
   Initializing core options...done
   compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1600004

   compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x30000b8

   compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x2c00fc1

   Initializing composite options...done
   Initializing opengl options...done
   Initializing decor options...done
   Initializing vpswitch options...done
   Initializing snap options...done
   Initializing mousepoll options...done
   Initializing resize options...done
   Initializing place options...done
   Initializing move options...done
   Initializing wall options...done
   Initializing grid options...done
   Initializing session options...done
   Initializing gnomecompat options...done
   Initializing animation options...done
   Initializing fade options...done
   compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't load plugin '/usr/lib/compiz/libunitymtgrabhandles.so' : /usr/lib/compiz/libunitymtgrabhandles.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10CompOption7setNameEPKcNS_4TypeE
   compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't load plugin 'unitymtgrabhandles'
   Initializing workarounds options...done
   Initializing scale options...done
   compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
   Initializing expo options...done
   Initializing ezoom options...done
   compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't load plugin '/usr/lib/compiz/libunityshell.so' : /usr/lib/compiz/libunityshell.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10CompOption7setNameEPKcNS_4TypeE
   compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't load plugin 'unityshell'
   compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000a0!
   compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
   compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000a3!
   compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
   compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000a6!
   compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
   Initializing addhelper options...done
   Initializing animationaddon options...done
   Initializing annotate options...done
   Initializing bench options...done
   Initializing blur options...done
   Initializing clone options...done
   Initializing colorfilter options...done
   Initializing commands options...done
   Initializing crashhandler options...done
   Initializing cube options...done
   Initializing cubeaddon options...done
   Initializing extrawm options...done
   Initializing fadedesktop options...done
   Initializing firepaint options...done
   Initializing group options...done
   Initializing imgjpeg options...done
   Initializing kdecompat options...done
   Initializing loginout options...done
   Initializing mag options...done
   Initializing maximumize options...done
   Initializing mblur options...done
   Initializing neg options...done
   Initializing notification options...done
   Initializing obs options...done
   Initializing opacify options...done
   Initializing put options...done
   Initializing reflex options...done
   Initializing resizeinfo options...done
   Initializing ring options...done
   Initializing rotate options...done
   Initializing scaleaddon options...done
   Initializing scalefilter options...done
   Initializing screenshot options...done
   Initializing shelf options...done
   Initializing shift options...done
   Initializing showdesktop options...done
   Initializing showmouse options...done
   Initializing splash options...done
   Initializing staticswitcher options...done
   Initializing switcher options...done
   Initializing td options...done
   Initializing thumbnail options...done
   Initializing trailfocus options...done
   Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
   Initializing unityshell options...done
   Initializing wallpaper options...done
   Initializing water options...done
   Initializing widget options...done
   Initializing winrules options...done
   Initializing wobbly options...done
   Setting Update "main_menu_key"
   Setting Update "run_key"
   ```

   Anything suspicious herein?

Comment: How exactly did the suggestions here not work?: http://askubuntu.com/q/17381/176889

Comment: What did you do to make your desktop disappear ?

Comment: [http://askubuntu.com/a/76951/176470](Here) Unity plugin is Enabled, Yet I disabled it then enabled again just to be sure, but no luck

Comment: @thom I tried to install wine after several fails! ... and the last one did eat up my desktop !

Comment: type in the terminal `unity --replace` if that gives you your desktop back then someone here will have the answers for you to fix it permanent

Comment: @thom I tried this one too from [http://askubuntu.com/a/63937/176470] (<-here) but that freezes the little way i have to run some progs without going to tty1-6 :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to reset your unity...

```
$ unity --reset
```

but beware that all your unity settigs will change to default

Comment: :please see above **Edit 3**.